# laravel : Error Call to a member function all() on array

Tags: php, laravel

This is used to export excel

My controllers:

```
public function reportExport(Request $request)
{
    return Excel::download(new ReportExport($request), 'LAPORAN ABSENSI.xlsx');
}
```

Export folder : ReportExport

```
return [
    "att_cross" => $att_cross,
    "belum_absen" => $belum_absen,
    "absen" => $absen,
];
```

but, when I return one of the data is successful, for example :

```
return $absen;
```

I want to display the contents of the variable $absent, $belum_absen, $att_cross but I get an error message "Call to a member function all() on array "
how can I display the data for these three parameters?

Comment: There isn't enough context here. Where do you have those `return` statements and what do they have to do with the error? Please post all relevant code (with context) and where the error actually occurs. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs for Excel package, you need to `map()` the output.